# github rebase and squash

Tags: git, github, pull-request

In an open source project managed on github I want to squash and rebase PRs. Github's drop down menu gives 3 options:
 1. Merge
 2. Squash and merge
 3. Rebase

So I want to do a combination of 3&2. I suppose my best option is to use git cli. However, if I squash & rebase on my local workstation terminal with git, will the Github GUI know that the PR was merged?

Answer (score 1):

If you squash and rebase locally, you have two options:

1. Push the result to the original branch for the Pull Request (using `git push --force`). This will overwrite the commits in the original Pull Request, updating the Pull Request with the resulting commit, but then you can merge into the main branch as normal.
2. Push the result to the main branch. This will leave the original Pull Request open, so you'll need to close it without merging.

Comment: Since it is an open source project, people I do not know may do PRs from forks I don't have permission to push to...

Comment: They may do a great job, and I want to give them the satisfaction of seeing their PRs merged. I just want the history to look the way I want it to...

Comment: Actually, on GitHub PRs have the *option* to give maintainers (i.e. people with write access) of the original repository the ability to push to the branch (even on a fork) the PR was made from.

Comment: @DopplerShift's is the right answer here: maintainers should feel free to make local changes to the PR's branch before merging.